# allow only A,B, 0-9 and * in input data filter in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript function to sanitize only numbers for input data

```
<input  type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">

function isNumberKey(evt){
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

But i want allow A, B, and * for input data. What should do this javascript code?

Comment: also don't use return in the event attribute. `<input  type="text" onkeypress="isNumberKey(event)">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `oninput` event instead, this will trigger even if user does a copy-paste

Try this way

```
<input  type="text" oninput="return isNumberKey(this)">

function isNumberKey( thisObj ){
    var regex = new RegExp("[0-9]+", "g");
    return regex.test( thisObj.value );
}
```

You can extend the regex to input to allow only **A,B, 0-9 and *** in input data

```
    var regex = new RegExp("[0-9AB*]+", "g");
```

```js
function isNumberKey(evt) {
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
  var regex = new RegExp("[0-9]+", "");
  return regex.test(String.fromCharCode( charCode ) );
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey( event )" oninput="return isNumberKey( event )">
```

Comment: It should be [0-9AB\\*]+

Comment: @sylvain1264 you don't need to escape `*` inside the character class `[]`

Comment: function isNumberKey(this) has Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token "this" error shown

Comment: Not working. when i click  g h o y i letters then this input form is allowed them

Comment: @OtgonbayarLamjav try the example attached

Answer (score -1):

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Regex to allow special characters, spaces and alphanumeric</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#btnValidate').click(function() {
var txt = $('#txtdesc').val();
var re = /^[ A-Za-z0-9_@./#&+-]*$/
if (re.test(txt)) {
alert('Valid Text')
}
else {
alert('Please Enter Valid Text');
return false;
}
})
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
Enter Text :<input type="text" id="txtdesc" />
<input type="button" id="btnValidate" value="Validate" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```